# How can I have a fallback service provider return a Mock of a type parameter that is not known at compile time

Tags: c#, blazor, moq, bunit

I'm writing a BUnit test for a Razor component that has injected dependencies like this:

```
@inject IMyFirstService FirstService
@inject IMySecondService SecondService

@code {

   // do stuff 

}
```

For my test, I created a fallback service provider `MoqServiceProvider` that I'm using to register my mocked dependencies.  **But I also want the fallback service provider to provide a `Moq<MyType>` instance by default for any types which I haven't explicitly mocked.**

The fallback service provider looks like this

```
public class MockServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> services = new();

    public void RegisterServices(params object[] serviceInstances)
    {
        this.services.Clear();

        foreach (object serviceInstance in serviceInstances)
        {
            if (serviceInstance is Mock)
            {
                this.services.Add(serviceInstance.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First(), (serviceInstance as Mock).Object);
            }
            else
            {
                this.services.Add(serviceInstance.GetType(), serviceInstance);
            }
        }
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (this.services.TryGetValue(serviceType, out object service))
        {
            return service;
        }
        else
        {
            // I want to return a Mock of serviceType here
            // something like return new Mock<serviceType>(), but I don't know how to do that
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this in a test (I'm using AutoFixture to provide the test parameters):

```
@inherits TestContext

@code{

    [Theory, AutoDomainData]
    public void TestSomething(
       Mock<IMyFirstService> myFirstService, 
       MockServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
       serviceProvider.RegisterServices(myFirstService);
       Services.AddFallbackServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
       var component = Render(@<MyComponent />);
   
       // do stuff to test
    }

}
```

If I run this, I'll get an error `Cannot provide a value for property 'SecondService' on type 'MyComponent'` since I haven't registered an instance of a `Mock<IMySecondService>` with `MockServiceProvider`.

How do I have `MockServiceProvider` return a mock of every type which I haven't registered explicity (something like `return Mock<serviceType`)?  Some of my Razor components have a lot of dependencies and I don't want to have to inject the ones that don't matter for each test.

Comment: I think you need to use a mocking framework. Here is a blog post that lists a few different options which works together with AutoFixture: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/09/NSubstituteAuto-mockingwithAutoFixture/

Comment: I'm using `Moq` and  `AutoFixture.AutoMoq`.  I've got that working for regular C# projects.  My difficulty is that I don't know how to work that in with BUnit's `TestServiceProvider` so that I can have a `Mock` returned by default if I haven't registered anything of the mocked type with the service provider.

Comment: bUnit will just try to use the fallback service provider you pass to it first. If the fallback IServiceProvider returns null when its `GetServices` method is called, then bUnit will try the built in service provider.

Comment: How your `GetServices` implementation in your `IServiceProvider` should work is entirely up to you, bUnit doesn't care about it.

Comment: I'm trying to get either the default service provider or fallback service provider to be configured automatically to return a `Mock<T>` instance for any type that I haven't explicitly configured it to return.  My problem is that I don't know how to get Moq to do something like `return Mock<typeof(MyClass>>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fallback service provider added to bUnit's root service provider is invoked if the root service provider cannot resolve a `GetService` request. With that info in mind, we can use Moq (or another mocking framework) and a little Reflection trickery to create a fallback service provider, which is really just something that implements the `IServiceProvider` interface, that will use Moq to create a mocked version of a requested service, when its `GetService` method is called.

### AutoMockingServiceProvider

This service provider will use Mock to create a mock of a requested service type once, and any subsequent requests will get the same type returned (they are saved in the `mockedTypes` dictionary).

The reason for this is that you can retrieve the same mocked instance of a type in both your test and in the component under test, which allows you to configure the mock in your test.

The `GetMockedService` extension method below makes it easy to pull out a `Mock<T>` from the service provider.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Moq;

public class AutoMockingServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo GenericMockFactory = typeof(Mock).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Of");
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> mockedTypes = new();

    public object? GetService(Type serviceType) => GetMockedService(serviceType);

    public object GetMockedService<T>() => GetMockedService(typeof(T));

    public object GetMockedService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (!mockedTypes.TryGetValue(serviceType, out var service))
        {
            var mockFactory = GenericMockFactory.MakeGenericMethod(serviceType);
            service = mockFactory.Invoke(null, Array.Empty<object>())!;
            mockedTypes.Add(serviceType, service);
        }

        return service;
    }
}

internal static class ServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static Mock<T> GetMockedService<T>(this IServiceProvider services)
        where T : class => Mock.Get<T>(services.GetService<T>()!);
}
```

NOTE: This code doesn't deal with any edge cases, so it might not work in all cases, but should serve as a good starting point.

### Example usage

Suppose we have the following component:

```
@inject IPerson Person
@Person.Name
```

That depends on this interface:

```cs
public interface IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

Then it can be tested like this:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    using var ctx = new TestContext();

    // Add the AutoMockingServiceProvider as the fallback service provider
    ctx.Services.AddFallbackServiceProvider(new AutoMockingServiceProvider());

    // Retrieves the mocked person from the service collection and configures it.            
    var mockedPerson = ctx.Services.GetMockedService<IPerson>();
    mockedPerson.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("Foo Bar");

    // Render component
    var cut = ctx.RenderComponent<MyComp>();

    // Verify content
    cut.MarkupMatches("Foo Bar");
}
```

This was tested with .NET 6 rc.1, Moq 4.16.1, and bunit 1.2.49.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it worked.  This taught me some stuff about reflection too.